# Check if image exists with url Doesn't work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I need in my project to show a image with other fields in loop so the image src differs every iteration, And i have to know if this image exists to make default src if not, the code what i will show you works only on Firefox not in Chrome and IE :

```
  var img = new Image();
    img.src = "www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg";
     var imgcheck = img.width;    

if (imgcheck==0) {
  alert("You have a zero size image");
} else { 
  alert('You have a good img');
   //Do something
}
```

Need your helps..

Comment: what you can do is on error you can specify a different image `image.onerror = "";` or in ur html itself like `<img src="myImage.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/defaultImage.jpg';" />`

Comment: *"`img.src = "www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg"`"* Well, that's wrong to start with. That's a **relative** URL, but it's clearly meant to be an absolute one. Add an `http://`, `https://`, or just `//` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the image `error` event.

```
$("<img/>")
    .on("load", function() { alert('You have a good img'); })
    .on("error", function() { alert('You got error'); })
    .attr("src", "http://www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg");
```

You need to append the newly created img to a DOM element like

```
$("<img/>")
    .on("load", function() { alert('You have a good img'); })
    .on("error", function() { alert('You got error'); })
    .attr("src", "http://www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg")
    .appendTo("body"); // append to body or any other element
```

Comment: I tried to do this , the problem is that the boucle is iterated before that the img say if it is loaded or there is an error

Comment: @Omar Sorry, I didnt get that?

Comment: @Omar: What's a "boucle"? Google says *"yarn with a looped or curled ply, or fabric woven from this yarn"* which seems...unrelated.

Comment: @Kiranvj I tied to do this code inside My Loop, there was problem the loop don't wait if the result of Test of img load or error is finishied and coninue looping ... so i can't show the image src in the associate element of the loop

Comment: Sorry i forgot boucle == Loop I got used to speak french

Comment: @kiranvj Itried it the append to `body` wasn't good idea because it show all images and what i need just chnage li href of each link in my Loop with the associate src

Answer (score 1):

Two problems there:

1. `img.src = "www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg"` That's a relative URL, but it's clearly meant to be an absolute one. Add an `http://`, `https://`, or just `//` in front of it.
2. You're not allowing for the asynchronicity of retrieving an image. **Before** setting the `src` (correctly), hook the `load` and `error` events. `load` tells you it worked. `error` tells you it didn't. But an immediately check for `width` won't tell you anything, because the image (probably) isn't loaded yet.

So:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // It loaded, check `width` if you think that's necessary
};
img.onerror = function() {
    // It failed to load
};
img.src = "http://www.Imagesource.com/Image.Jpeg";
```

Note that

1. We're hooking the events **before** setting `src`. That's important, particularly if there's any chance of the image being in cache.
2. Both events will happen **asynchronously**.

Comment: @Omar: Examples should be representative of the real use case. And #1 is a minor part of the answer.

Comment: The is the problem that the events are asynchronously , because i have to put them in a Loop and change current iterate with this events results,.. Can you resolve it please ?

Comment: @Omar I think I understand your problem now. You might need a function closure to keep track of which image goes with which link: [demo](https://output.jsbin.com/wiyuluripa/1) (you can see the code by clicking on the upper right corner).

Comment: Thank You i will tray it